# Updating React/Redux State from Window function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a scenario where I'm trying to update a React/Redux state from a function that's placed on the Window. The function on the window is unable to access the function that's in the React component. Any idea how to bind that function in this kind of setup? This snippet just has a console log where the Redux call would go.

```js
class MyComponent extends Component {
  

  updateRedux = a => {
    console.log(a)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.windowFunction = function(a) {
      this.updateRedux(a)
    }    
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Stuff />
    )
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` is not accessible inside your function, you need to bind it.

Try with:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

  updateRedux = a => {
    console.log(a)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.windowFunction = function(a) {
      this.updateRedux(a)
    }.bind(this)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Stuff />
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: no, updateRedux implemented as arrow function, it is bound already, no need for .bind(this)

Comment: @VladislavSorokin I'm not talking about binding `updateRedux`. I'm talking about binding `function(a) ...`

Comment: or he can make windowFunction an arrow function

Comment: Make the windowFunction an arrow function solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you meant that you want to update Redux state with some action (this is the only way to update Redux state by design), then you need to make this action and its functions available to your Component with connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component)

Comment: I know how to update Redux. This code is just a simplified example of what I’m trying to accomplish. The console log is in place of where a Redux action would go.

Answer (score 0):

One of the comments above about converting the windowFunction to an arrow function resolved the issue. Thanks!

```js
class MyComponent extends Component {

  updateRedux = a => {
    console.log(a)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.windowFunction = a => {
      this.updateRedux(a)
    }.bind(this)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Stuff />
    )
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is separate the concerns using a presenter and a connected
component, using react-redux. I am assuming you know of this library, comment
if you need more details.

```
// Simple "presenter", the getComponentData is used to get the data for the
// redux store.
class MyComponentPresenter extends Component {

  // returns data for redux
  getComponentData () {}

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.updateRedux(this); // update Redux
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Stuff />
    )
  }

}


// This component has the exact same interface, but comes with a updateRedux
// props which automatically dispatches an action
export const MyComponent = connect(null, {
  updateRedux(componentInstance) {
    return {
      type: "updateRedux"
    };
  }
});

// in the reducer
//
function reducer (state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "updateRedux":
      return ...
  }
}
```

No more need for globally available function (which in your example is redefined for each instance of `MyComponents` which is probably not what you want).